# multiple screen size issue

Tags: java, android, xml, screen-size

Base on my understanding, The supporting multiple screen size is work on 3.2 or later. any below of that version, it will not auto detect screen size and choose the correct layout folder.

**Correct me if i am wrong**

However, my case was i am running an application on an emulator and two difference size and version devices.

> Emulator : 1.6 version with QVGA. It does auto detect screen size and choose correct layout folder.
>
> first device : 2.2 version with small size (QVGA). It does not auto detect screen size and choose wrong layout folder
>
> second device : 4.0.4 version with Nexus S-medium size (HVGA). It does auto detect screen size and choose correct layout folder.

my manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="426" >
</supports-screens>
```

my folder

> res/drawable
>
> res/layout
>
> res/layout-small

I don't create new set of drawable because the image can show clearly if using small layout so i don't bother that one.

What if i upgrade my first device from 2.2 to 3.2 or later, then the device will auto detect and choose correct folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below link will guide you on how to go about with it.

```
http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/61895.aspx#
```

Comment: it should automatically choose the screen size

Comment: sorry for late reply, actually my one with your provided guildline not much difference

Comment: however, it cannot detect, i suspend is it android version or device brand causing unable to detect?

Comment: 1 more thing, i am using pixel instead of dp or dip

Comment: Dont use pixel that is where the problem is u have to use dip(device independent pixel) which aligns itself based on the device.try that it will work

Comment: it is very hard to amend at currently moment, this is because it involved many layouts, so any other solution instead of changing to dip?

Comment: is it guarantee that after change to dip, the device will auto detect and choose correct layout folder?

Comment: It was amazing, i port into Samsung 2.3.3 small screen, it does auto detect

Comment: i did not use dip, i did not change anything and just change difference device to install same apps, the two devices were 2.2 and 2.3 respectively and 2.3 works but 2.2 not work

Comment: u mean devices were not proper? But dip is device independent pixel which automatically sets based sizes based on the device.its better to always use dip.

Comment: yup, dip is better but earlier of this project, we decided to use pixel then must go ahead, i think HTC with 2.2 cannot auto detect but samsung 2.3 can auto detect screen size and choose correct layout folder